# Sending DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE results to external file in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, database-migration

I have few functions containing select queries and `dbms_output.put_line` statements. Further, I am trying to execute them via a script (master.sql) and need to send their corresponding `dbms_output` results to their respective text files.

Sample function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myschema.my_func1() RETURNS VOID  AS $func$

DECLARE 
     cur_fetch_my_data CURSOR IS
    select col1,col2 from myschema.table1;
BEGIN

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('column 1'||CHR(9)||'column 2');
      for data_cur in cur_fetch_my_data LOOP           
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(data_cur.col1||CHR(9)||data_cur.col2);
      END LOOP;

END;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Script for executing functions:

```
--master.sql    
begin
dbms_output.serveroutput(true);
    end;
    \o DUMP_OF_func1.txt
    SELECT myschema.my_func1();
    \o DUMP_OF_func2.txt
    SELECT myschema.my_func2();
```

After above script execution, all dbms_output results are printed on console but not in text file. Only thing which is dumped into text file is

```
my_func1
------------

(1 row)
```

Further, i tried changing the master script. I changed

```
dbms_output.serveroutput(true)
```

to

```
dbms_output.serveroutput(false)
```

After doing this, console output did not print. But dump into text file remained same.

Can anyone please tell me how I can divert `dbms_output` results to their text files?

Comment: There is no `dbms_output` in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But then how come the dbms_output present in my function definition printing statements on my console?

Comment: You either created that manually or you are using some commercial version of Postgres (e.g. EnterpriseDB) which added support for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes it is enterprisedb.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Also, these functions are custom made. If you have any other alternative to these dbms_output, that will also be an acceptable solution.

Comment: You may want to look into **raise notice**.